# inserting numbers into an array and checking

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logic

**I wanted to insert numbers into this array, so that the user could choose how many to put until he wanted to leave.**

1. The first problem - when the user puts in option 2 to exit, it still
   asks for the number once more before it exits, and also inserts it
   into the array.
2. I tried to create a check so that if the user puts in a number
   already added previously, it won't be possible, but it's not working
   either.

```
numbers = []
option = 1

loop do
  if option == 1
    puts 'To enter a number type 1 - To exit type 2'
    option = gets.chomp.to_i
    
    print 'Type: '
    number_user = gets.chomp.to_i
    if number_user == numbers
      puts 'This number has already been entered!'
    elsif
      numbers << number_user
    end

  elsif option == 2
    puts "Bye!"
    puts "Entered numbers - #{numbers}"
    return
  else
    puts "Invalid option"
    return
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you explain what this has to do with [tag:ruby-on-rails]? I am a little confused. Are you trying to get inputs from a remote web browser? `puts` and `gets` *cannot possibly work* for that! You will need to find a completely different solution.

Comment: @JörgWMittag i am studying, trying to improve my programming logic in simple problems like this, which i still have a lot of difficulties with and get in the way of my career. even if you have any study tips for me to improve my logic, to be able to do tasks in the project i work on from scratch, to become a better programmer, i am accepting.

Answer (score 1):

Use `break` to break out of the loop. And `Array#include?` to test if the number has already been input:

```
numbers = []

loop do
  option = gets.chomp.to_i
  if option == 1
    puts 'To enter a number type 1 - To exit type 2'
    option = gets.chomp.to_i
    print 'Type: '
    number_user = gets.chomp.to_i
    if number_user == numbers
      puts 'This number has already been entered!'
    elsif
      numbers << number_user
    end
  elsif option == 2
    break
  else
    puts "Invalid option"
  end
end
```

However unless you really hate your users or are building a numpad interface you can just let them exit by leaving the input blank or by inputting an exit character ("q" or "Q") instead of having to enter 1 over and over:

```
numbers = []

loop do
  puts 'Please enter a number (or leave blank to exit):'
  input = gets.chomp
  if ["", "Q"].include?(input.upcase)
    break
  elsif numbers.to_i.include?(input.to_i)
    puts 'This number has already been entered!'
  else
    numbers << input.to_i
  end
end
puts "Bye!"
puts "Entered numbers - #{numbers}"
```

Comment: nice man, the second way was cleaner too, it seemed like a better way to do it, thanks for that.